# SendDataMessage is not working on 4G network

Tags: android, message

My app sends a port directed data message to itself. This is currently working on a 2G or 3G network but it is not working on a 4G network. There is no error message but no message is sent.

Comment: is that problem on specific phone or other phone types as well? eventually which version of android are you working on? does your network provider offer 4G?

Comment: I m testing it on marshmallow I own 2 phones samsung on 5 pro and Moto x style both are 4g capable I can make and receive 4g calls but not able to send data message. When I changed my sim 2g/3g the same code is working.

Comment: ok, would you mind sharing your code that so i can test it on my device to see if i can contribute with a solution.

Comment: @maytham: thank you,  actually today I figured out that no app on my phone is able to send sms using 4g network even the default sms app is not able to send sms. This issue is related to carrier, only carrier app is able to send & receive sms.